# Where should I create my network dataset in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I want to create a new network dataset from a street layer. Should I create it in a normal file or in a personal geodatabase?

Comment: What do you mean, "normal file?"

Comment: well, not in a geodatabase. It seeems to work but I wanted to know if its better to do it in a geodatabase or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A network dataset must reside within a [feature dataset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002300000001000000). A feature dataset can be created in either a file geodatabase (folder.gdb) or a personal geodatabase (filename.mdb). You can't create one in a shapefile, if that's what you mean by 'normal'. Note you'll need to add the street layer to the network dataset in order to build a network from it, and there may be some cleanup necessary/involved in building a useable network. You may want to run through [this ArcGIS help tutorial](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00470000005t000000).